# Can I get examples for static keyword in header file?

Tags: c++, static

static.h

```
static int y = 20;
static int& f(){
    static int x = 0;
    return x;
}
```

general.h

```
int x = 10;
int& g(){
    static int x = 0;
    return x;
}
```

outer.h

```
#include"general.h"
#include"static.h"

void h(){
    x = 20;//static
    y = 20;//non static

    f() = 20;//static
    g() = 20;//non static
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"static.h"
#include"general.h"
#include"outer.h"

int main(){
    h();
    std::cout<<"static objects are independent in each file\n";
    std::cout<<"x : "<<x<<", f() : "<<f()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"non static objects are only one in every file.\n ";
    std::cout<<"y : "<<y<<", g() : "<<g()<<std::endl;
}
```

I want to simulate how static keyword changes code behavior.
but, I don't know how to do that...
How do I do?

.....................................................
I split my code.
static.h

```
static int x = 0;
static int& f(){
    static int k = 0;
    return k;
}
void call_static();
```

static.cpp

```
#include"static.h"

void call_static(){
    x = 10;
    f() = 10;
}
```

general.h

```
int y = 0;
int& g(){
    static int z = 0;
    return z;
}
void call_general();
```

general.cpp

```
#include"general.h"
void call_general(){
    y = 10;
    g() = 10;
}
```

Static codes are compiled well, but non static codes aren't compiled.

error code

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/general-539e11.o: in function `g()':
general.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `g()'; /tmp/main-5f12cd.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/general-539e11.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `y'; /tmp/main-5f12cd.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
clang-12: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is it normal?

Comment: You need to get different translation units involved to see a difference. Create 2 headers `A.hpp` and `B.hpp` declaring functions `functionA` and `functionB`, create `A.cpp` and `B.cpp` with implementations of those functions using the static symbols, use both functions in your main and link everything together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you've shown there's only one `.cpp` file.
`.h` files don't actually count as "Translation Units", only `.c` and `.cpp` files are translation units.
The reason for that is that `.h` files are added to a program using `#include`.
`#include` literally copy-pastes the specified file into the current file, making it just 1 big file.
If you had multiple `.c` or `.cpp` files (or a mix of both, that's OK as well), you'll be able to see the effects that the `static` keyword has on variable/function visibility.

Remember to NEVER `#include` `.c` or `.cpp` files!
Instead, you should add them to your program seperately.
If you are using Visual Studio (not VS Code) simply adding a new source file should automatically add it to the program, without you needing to mention it anywhere.
If you are using another compiler, add the name of your `.c` or `.cpp` files to the list of files to be compiled.

I'd reccomend reading about translation units.
you can do that at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming) and [What is a "translation unit" in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c), but I'd also highly recommend just looking up "c and c++ translation units" on google and learning about them in general.

Have fun coding!

Comment: Thank you! I split my codes and It work. But, non-static codes aren't compile. Why is that?

Comment: What files do you have now? What's written in them? Do you wanna maybe upload a `.zip` of all of them for me to look?  
What do you use to compile the files? Visual Studio/GCC/something else?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12dp3eTYyQrP2UzfL-_MP1kzxefC0_nvR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: debian, clang-12

Comment: I've found your issue! when you do something like `int y;` at the global scope, you might think that that's a declaration - kinda like declaring the name and args of a function, without the actual code inside it.
But variables are not like functions in C, and every time you `int y;` at the global scope, you cause a new allocation of memory. But C doesn't allow 2 variables to have the same name ("`y`" here), because then it wouldn't know which of them you mean when you refer to "`y`".
The solution is to replace any declaration to `extern int y;`, and only have one `int y;` in one `.cpp` file.

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading about the `extern` keyword in general! :)

Comment: Thank you for kind answer!! I finally do it!

Comment: Happy to help 